# How to implement a React Apple sign-in without a popup

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sign-in-with-apple

I have been working in react web app where I have a SIWA button. Due to some campatability issues, I could not use popup for siginin, so I rather implemented redirecting user to a seperate apple's signin page, and after sucessful siginin apple would redirect user back to my webapp. I had set the response type to `fragments`, so that apple would add the `id_token` to the url itself when redirectring, which I could then use in my own webapp.

This approach was working fine till now because I hadn't added email or name to the scope for SIWA. But now I had to add them both, so that I would be able to retrieve them later using the `id_token`. But it seems apple doesnot allow adding scopes without setting the `responseType` to `form_post`. If I am not wrong, I am supposed to create a `POST` endpoint in my backend which will accept the given `form_post` data. But if I did so, how will I be able to redirect user back to my frontend, since the redirect url for SIWA would have to be set to the backend's endpoint?

Bascially, my requirements are, I should be able to redirect user back to the frontend after successful login, and the frontend should also get the `id_token`. It doesn't matter if that involves my backend or not. And also its very important that I do so without using the popup signin.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the POST endpoint return a 302 status and a `Location` header of your front end URL.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302